# How to speed up data transfer over socket?

Tags: java, android, sockets

Currently I am using this code on both Server and Client Side. Client is an android device.

```
BufferedOutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream(),10000000);
BufferedInputStream sin = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream(),10000000);
os.write("10000000\n".getBytes());
os.flush();
for (int i =0;i<10000000;i++){
    os.write((sampleRead[i]+" ").getBytes());
    }
os.flush();
```

The problem is that this code takes about 80 secs to transfer data from android client to server while it takes only 8 seconds to transfer the data back from server to client. The code is same on both sides and buffer is also same. I also tried with different buffer sizes but the problem is with this segment

```
for (int i =0;i<10000000;i++){
     os.write((sampleRead[i]+" ").getBytes());
}
```

The  buffering takes most of the time while the actual transfer takes only about 6-7 seconds on a 150mbps hotspot connection. What could be the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Using such a large buffer size may be contra-productive because you delay the writes too much. Buffer sizes of a few kB are usually enough. This does not explain the speed difference though. How are server and client connected? Any asymmetric connection?

Comment: They are connected through a TCP socket on a hotspot connection with 150mbps link speed. The problem though is not with data transfer but with buffering.

Comment: Your android client may have problems to keep the huge buffers in memory and therefore does some swapping.

Comment: Okay I'll check again with a smaller buffer size of say 100kB. Just a minute.

Comment: Also, split your write into two statements instead of the string concatenation.

Comment: So I combined the answers and comments. Instead of pusing numbers directly to BufferedOutputStream, I am using a StringBuilder to act like a buffer and when it has 100000 I write the String obtained from this StringBuilder to to BufferedOutputStream. Now this code has brought down the send time to 10 seconds approx. If you can suggest something even better than please do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, as a commenter has already noted, using a monstrously large buffer is likely to be counter productive.  Once your stream buffer is bigger than the size of a network packet, app-side buffering loses its effectiveness.  (The data in your "big" buffer needs to be split packet-sized chunks by the TCP/IP stack before it goes onto the network.)  Indeed, if the app-side buffer is really large, you may find that your data gets stuck in the buffer for a long time waiting for the buffer to fill ... while the network is effectively idle.

(The `Buffered...` readers, writers and streams are primarily designed to avoid lots of syscalls that transfer tiny amounts of data.  Above 10K or so, the buffering doesn't performance help much.)

The other thing to now is that in a lot of OS environments, the network throughput is actually limited by virtualization and default network stack tuning parameters.  To get a better throughput, you may need to tune at the OS level.

Finally, if your network path is going over a network path that is congested, has a  high end-to-end latency or links with constrained data rate, then you are unlikely to get fast data transfers no matter how you tune things.

(Compression might help ... if you can afford the CPU overhead at both ends ... but some data links already do compression transparently.)

Answer (score 2):

You could compress the data transfer, it will save a lot of memory and well to transfer a compress stream of data is cheaper... For that you need to implement compress logic in client side and decompress logic in server side, see GZIPInputStream... And try reducing the buffer size is huge for a mobile device...